# Compare DB2 Date with RPG date

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have this doubt on how to compare DB2 date, time fields with RPG date and time fields

```
 If (Zpschdt < CurDat or (ZPschdt = Curdat and  
    (%Time() - ZPschtm) > 30));
```

For example in the above piece of code, Curdat is a character field which contains date value populated using below line

```
CurDat = %CHAR(%DATE():*MDY);
```

%Time() that is the current time needs to be subtracted from ZPschtm which is a DB2 time field and needs to be checked if the difference is greater that 30 minutes.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: (%Char(Zpschdt) < CurDat or (%Char(ZPschdt) = Curdat and  
(%Dec(%Time()) - %Dec(ZPschtm)) > 30)); Does this seem to be a good job?

Comment: RPG Dates and DB2 dates are exactly the same. At least since RPG 4 was released in 1996. None the less, many old timers, and those they train persist in loading dates and times in numeric, or even character fields. New programs should use the native support for dates and times, both in RPG and DB2.

Comment: Shouldn't this be if ts < %timestamp(); and not if ts > %timestamp(); as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I fixed that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find schedule dates and times that are more than 30 minutes old, and the timeframe needs to cross days, you are going to have to use timestamps rather than dates and times. To deal with your situation, define a timestamp field, assign the schedule date and time, add 30 minutes to the timestamp, and compare that to the current timestamp. Like this:

```
dcl-s ts     Timestamp;

ts = zschdt + zschtm + %minutes(30);
if ts < %timestamp();
  // do something here
endif;
```

Comment: Sorry cant add new fields or change existing ones.. will have to think of a way to find this with the change date and change time fields

Comment: what do you mean can't add new fields. no need to add a new field to the database. Certainly you can define a work variable in the program?

Comment: Oh now I get it.. sorry yes will try this

Comment: This might be a silly question..but how do you develop thinking skills like this? I just couldn't think about all this. Is it just raw experience or does it have something to do with DNA or Genes.. Just frustrated at myself

Comment: I don't know, maybe some of each. My wife couldn't do this in a million years, of course I couldn't do some of the things she does. I will leave a comment on the question concerning a possible point of confusion.

Comment: Murph.. You the best.. you a rockstar!

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a character variable to a date variable.

Generally, you have to either convert the character to date, or the date to character.

Since you character variable is formatted *MDY, it'd be easier to convert it to date; otherwise you'd need to change the format to YYYYMMDD in order to compare it as a numeric or character.

```
If Zpschdt < %Date(CurDat:*MDY)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I have found a good enough solution for this as below:

```
If ( %Diff(%Date():Zpschdt:*Days) > 1 or    
(%Diff(%Date():Zpschdt:*Days) = 0 and       
%Diff(%Time():ZPschtm:*Minutes) > 30));
```

The first condition of Or - `%Diff(%Date():Zpschdt:*Days) > 1` checks if Current date is ahead of the change date at least by one day.

The Second condition :

```
(%Diff(%Date():Zpschdt:*Days) = 0 and       
    %Diff(%Time():ZPschtm:*Minutes) > 30))
```

checks if the Change date is same as current day and if Current time is ahead of change time by at least 30 minutes..

Does this look good enough? Seems to do the job..

Comment: Maybe it does the job in most cases, but what about around midnight? if `ZPSCHDT = 01/10/2017` and `ZPSCHTM = 23:45:00`, then on  `01/31/2017` between `00:00:00` and `00:15:00`, your if statement will return true though the real difference in time is less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Still a lot of confusions though.. Are you asking to declare Ts as a Char variable?  If so I guess there is a need to convert Zpschdt and Zpschtm to Char using %Char. Also, before the concatenation add 30 mins to Zpschtm?

Comment: No, timestamp. RPG supports native Dates, Times, and Timestamps. The fact that you are using `%Diff`, `%Date`, and `%Time` tells me that you are using RPG 4. Just use the native date time support.